# Can I embed google blogger site into my website

Tags: html, blogger

I have a blogger blog and I have already successfully had the domain set to a subdomain of my website e.g http://blog.jthink.net

But how do I actually embed the blog onto my website so that it has same header and footer as my main website ( http://www.jthink.net ) so it's more like the way they have done it [here](http://blog.beatunes.com/)

Is it even possible with blogger?

Comment: `<iframe src='http://blog.jthink.net' />` make sure http/https is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whilst iFrames is literally speaking the way to embed the blog on your webpage it means you cant give people links to a particular post within the blog, so it doesnt treally work very well.

In the end I found you could simply the customize the blogger template to make your blog look like your other pages, I found this worked better than using iframes.

Comment: Good observation. 1) set up a system to message the href information back and forth across the iFrame boundary or 2) write CSS/HTML twice and manage in two places AND deal with routing + pagination on the standalone site.

Answer (score 10):

Just use an iFrame for this purpose. To embed a webpage in an `iFrame` in your own blog of a website is equivalent to copying that webpage into your own website or blog.

Adjust the `width` and `height` to your own values that you would like to use.

```
 <iframe src ="URL of the website you want to embed" width="100%" height="500"> </iframe>
```

You could also add

```
<p>Your browser does not support iFrames.</p>
```

To notify if a user uses a browser that does not support iFrame.

So the complete code will be

```
<iframe src ="URL of the website you want to embed" width="100%" height="500">
<p>Your browser does not support iFrames.</p>
</iframe>
```

Comment: is there any plugin like facebook's embedded posts(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-posts) where we can display only 1 blogger post in my html page??

Comment: might be useful to use in your blogger url the mobile version of it, ending your url with `?m=1`. You can also costumize your iframe: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe

Answer (score 3):

I'm a bit late to the party but If you want an alternative to straight out embedding your blog you could use the the [Blogger api](https://developers.google.com/blogger/)?

To my mind that would be the best solution.

Comment: I just saw this post. I'm working on adding Blogger blogs to my Ruby on Rails app. Have you implemented this in one of your projects? If so which API version did you implement, 1 (deprecated), 2 or 3? How long did it take you?

Comment: @PamelaCook-LightBeCorp I've never actually used the API, I'm just aware of it.I would try to implement version 3 first. It's a rest API so it's platform agnostic. If you are familiar with the technology, it should be quick and easy to implement although, that said, I've never worked with Ruby so I can't be sure.

Comment: The reason I was looking at this was for SEO purposes. I tend to develop my own logic but thought implementing the Blogger API might be a quicker option. It was not clear how SEO would work on my website using it and I'm not familiar enough with it to implement it quickly. I have started developing my own blog code in my application. It is quicker and I will know the SEO will be from my website and not the blogger link.

Answer (score 2):

Either you can used an iFrame or you can used an Individual div for the Particular site. 
Then you can embedded it within the site.

Be assure that you can adjust the Width and height of the frame or div through the CSS. 
here is a simple code which help to embedded the blogger site within your existing site.

```
<iframe src ="www.xyz.com" width="100%" height="100%"> </iframe>
```

If for any reason the browser doesn't support iFrame you can notify the user for it. By Using the Paragraph or any other tag.

Comment: How does the <div> idea work is that instead of <iframe> or as well as ?

Comment: With in <div> you can used <iframe> it will help you to design your iframe.

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised nobody suggested RSS feed subscriptions.

If it's a blogger site then you can just subscribe to the standard site feed in your current CMS (content management system).  See this link for more information: support.google.com/blogger/answer/97933?hl=en

In fact, I think this is exactly how the blog you linked to achieved their effect.  All the navigation baggage of the original blogger site is left behind and only the content of each post is automatically reposted via RSS content subscription -> blog.beatunes.com/atom.xml

```
Tools to achieve this:
-Wordpress: wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rss-aggregator
-Joomla!: extensions.joomla.org/extension/simple-rss-feed-reader
-Drupal: drupal.org/node/326575  
-SharePoint: lol *highfive*
```

Comment: While this is interesting, you would lose HTML structure and CSS styling, and end up with duplicate code that you have to maintain in 2 places. Better to write responsive HTML/CSS for different devices, browsers, and sizes. The answer should have to deal with Cross Origin Resource Sharing and whitelisting..

Answer (score 0):

You can use iframe to embed your blog onto the website.
for example, http://jsfiddle.net/pablofiumara/mCfAe/

References:  `https://developer.mozilla.org/ko/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe`

Answer (score -2):

iframes are best for this. Most browsers support them.
Maybe you could use adobe business catalyst page templates?