# Posting google blog spot blogs on personal website

Tags: javascript

I want to get all of my blogs from blog spot and put their links on a personal page, but I want to do this automatically. And if it is possible to get their content and generate a new page with it. How do I do those?

Comment: I think this might help you [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34313391/can-i-embed-google-blogger-site-into-my-website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34313391/can-i-embed-google-blogger-site-into-my-website)

Comment: it does, thanks a lot !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I embed google blogger site into my website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34313391/can-i-embed-google-blogger-site-into-my-website)